# Playwright Not Launching Within Electron App

Tags: javascript, electron, playwright

I'm currently facing an issue with integrating Playwright into my Electron app. The Playwright code works perfectly when executed as a standalone script, but when integrated into my Electron app, Playwright doesn't seem to launch at all.

```
//main.js

const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const childProcess = require("child_process");

function createWindow() {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  win.loadFile("index.html");
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow);

app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
  if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on("activate", () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow();
  }
});

// Listen for IPC message to start Playwright automation
ipcMain.on("startPlaywright", (event, data) => {
  const scriptPath = path.join(__dirname, "playwright-process.js");

  // Start the separate Playwright process with username and password as arguments
  childProcess.fork(scriptPath, [data.username, data.password]);
});
```

/

```
// script.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const loginForm = document.getElementById("login-form");
  loginForm.addEventListener("submit", async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
    const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");

    const username = usernameInput.value;
    const password = passwordInput.value;

    // Send username and password to main process using IPC
    ipcRenderer.send("startPlaywright", { username, password });
  });
});
```

/

```
// playwright-process.js
const { chromium } = require("playwright");

async function startPlaywrightAutomation(username, password) {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto("https://www.example.com");

  // Use the received username and password here
  console.log("Received username:", username);
  console.log("Received password:", password);

  // Continue with the rest of the Playwright automation
  // ...

  await page.screenshot({ path: "screenshot.png" });

  // Wait for 5 seconds
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

  await browser.close();
}

// Parse the username and password from command line arguments
const username = process.argv[2];
const password = process.argv[3];

// Start Playwright automation with the provided username and password
startPlaywrightAutomation(username, password);
```

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I've verified that Playwright is installed correctly, as it works when executed outside of the Electron app.
I've confirmed that my paths and file structures are accurate.
I've attempted different versions of Electron and Playwright to check for compatibility issues.
I've checked the developer console for any error messages or warnings, but there are none related to Playwright.
Additional Information:

My Electron app functions as expected without the Playwright integration.
I'm using the recommended communication methods between Electron's main and renderer processes.
I've tried using both headless and non-headless modes for Playwright.
Expected Outcome:
I expect Playwright to launch and execute its tasks within my Electron app just as it does when run as a standalone script.

Any assistance or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "Integrate with my Electron"?
I'm currently testing with Playwright an Electron app, but I have my test script loading my installed Electron app via /Application folder (Osx path) and after loaded I can perform my e2e tests. Is what you want to achieve?

Comment: Does Playwright get launched as expected when you run your Electron app in dev environment?